# Yii2 submit form and return the result in Pjax container

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, pjax

How to submit the form, process the data, send it to action and in the end, place it in the pjax container? I know solution where the pjax container is wrapping the form but my case is something like this:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
...
...
...
ActiveForm::end();

some html

Pjax::begin(['id' => 'container']);

The result from the controller action goes here

Pjax::end():
```

I've seen solution like this with javascript/jQuery function along ago but can't find it now. Can some give me example or at least some useful link. Thank you in advance! P.s. Red a lot of articles but couldn't fine something for my case.

Comment: so you want to say that your form or form inputs are not part of the pjax container and it is just for showing the message?

Comment: Yes. That's the case.

Comment: what i cant understand is that why are you even using the pjax container for this purpose why not a simple div if it is about a message to be displayed only , you can do that even wrapping the form inside the pjax container too

Comment: I have multiview with 500 items in the pjax container.

Comment: I did it by wrapping the active form in pjax container. `myDropzone.on('complete', function () {
        $.pjax.relad({container: '#pjax-slider'});
    });` This did the trick.

Comment: just a notice, Yii2 is dropping pjax for next Yii versions. I would avoid it!